# Passing array to function: array must have 'Sized' type

Tags: rust

I've constructed an array of arrays like this:

```
let mut my_array = [[false; WIDTH]; HEIGHT];
```

where `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are previously defined constants.

I want to pass the whole array to a function, and change the values within the array, although not the size/length of the array.

I've tried:

```
array_func(&my_array);  // (in main function)

fn array_func(arr: &mut [[bool]]) {
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```

And I get the error:

```
the trait 'std::marker::Sized' is not implemented for '[bool]'
note: `[bool]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
note: slice and array elements must have `Sized` type
```

The size of my array should be known at compile time - I can't change the size of an array. At least, I thought the `let mut my_array` meant I could change the values within the array but not the size of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> the trait 'std::marker::Sized' is not implemented for '[bool]'
> ```

There are essentially 2 forms of arrays in Rust:

- `[T; N]` is an array of `N` `T`s, it is `Sized`.
- `[T]` is an array of `T` of size only known at run-time, it is NOT `Sized`, and can only really be manipulated as a slice (`&[T]`).

The problem you have in your code is that in `[[bool]]`, the inner `[bool]` is therefore NOT `Sized`, and only `Sized` elements can be stored in an array.

The simplest solution is probably to update your function signature to correctly annotate the array sizes:

```
fn array_func(arr: &mut [[bool; WIDTH]; HEIGHT]) {
}
```

It is possible to coerce a `&[T; N]` to a `&[T]`, so you could also use:

```
fn array_func(arr: &mut [[bool; WIDTH]]) {
}
```

However, it is NOT possible to coerce a `[[T; N]]` to `[&[T]]`, and thus, not possible to coerce a `&[[T; N]; M]` into a `&[&[T]; M]` (and thus `&[&[T]]`), because an array and a reference to an array have a different memory representation and thus this would be an O(M) operation (and require a new array of size `M`).

> At least, I thought the `let mut my_array` meant I could change the values within the array but not the size of the array.

This is correct indeed, the dimensions of the array are part of its type, and `mut` only allows changing the value not the type.