# Confusion about ownership/lifetime in Rust

Tags: rust

Here is some functions to combine two things to one:

```rust
// It's right. move v1/v2's ownership in when call, move v's ownership back when finish.
fn combine_v(v1: Vec<i32>, v2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let v = vec![1,2,3];
    return v;
}

// It's right with lifetime statements. I can return a `&str` type var.
fn combine_s<'a>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    let s = "123";
    return s;
}

// It's not right. 
fn combine<'a>(v1: &'a [i32], v2: &'a [i32]) -> &'a [i32] {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    // cannot return reference to local variable `a`
    return &a;
}

// It's not right. 
// Error: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time
fn combine_1(v1: [i32], v2: [i32]) -> [i32] {
    let a = [1,2,3];
    return a;
}
```

So I have questions:

1. Why you can return `&str` type but not a `&[i32]`? Why `&str`'s value not dropped when function finish?
2. (How) Can I write a function that accept `&[i32]`s, and return a new `&[i32]`?
3. (How) Can I write a function that accept `[i32]`s, and return a new `[i32]`, when the length cannot be determined at compilation time?
4. Why `[i32]` must have a length, but `&[i32]` not?

Comment: so many question in one question

Comment: Btw: [Why is using return as the last statement in a function considered bad style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961879)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

Comment: @Stargateur I'll break it down into a few small problems

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to your subquestions:

> 1) Why you can return `&str` type but not a `&[i32]`? Why `&str`'s value not dropped when function finish?

Because when your code compiles, it is referred as `'static` lifetime. Thus it is not dropped when function finished.

> 2) How can I write a function that accept `&[i32]`s, and return a new `&[i32]`?

The signature of your function is correct. But in the implementation, you need to specify your declaration with `'static` lifetime or at least write it in the way that compiler can refer it as `'static`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

> 3) How can I write a function that accept `[i32]`s, and return a new `[i32]`, when the length cannot be determined at compilation time?

To use them as you wanted, you need to use `Box` and change your function signature as following: [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.1/std/boxed/struct.Box.html)

```rust
fn combine_1(v1: Box<[i32]>, v2: Box<[i32]>) -> Box<[i32]>
```

> 4) Why `[i32]` must have a length, but `&[i32]` not?

There are essentially 2 forms of arrays in Rust: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864442/passing-array-to-function-array-must-have-sized-type)

- `[T; N]` is an array of `N` `T`s, it is `Sized`.
- `[T]` is an array of `T` of size only known at run-time, it is NOT `Sized`, and can only really be manipulated as a slice `(&[T])`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e45199e024ca5842d4aeb6968274a5d)